# Indentity Column vs GUID for Scaling Up

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am designing a SQL database for the Azure cloud and I am wondering about the use of IDENTITY vs GUID columns for primary keys, especially when scaling up the database.  I already understand the size, performance and clustering differences between them but I am concerned about what will happen to an IDENTITY column if we scale up OR Geo-replicate the database?  Would using an IDENTITY column eventually catch up to us in a bad way if we needed to scale?

I've tried searching online for best practices regarding this in SQL Azure but all the documentation I am finding seems to be from 2010 or 2012.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to be concerned when writing to multiple different primary databases that operate over the same dataset. This could be the case if you shard you DB for example. Whenever you only have one DB you write to, there should be no problem.

Geo-replication is not a concern as the secondaries are (if at all accessible) read only and IDs are only generated on the primary. The IDENTITY will work correctly after failovers.

Comment: Thanks Jan!  As far as shards are concerned is that something I would only need to worry about if I we were in the Terrabytes of data level?  Or storing large binary files?

Comment: Yes, if you exceed the max size that a single Azure DB can hold (currently 500GB in the Premium levels) you would have to start to shard [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started/). Check out SQL Servers compression [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) options though and consider columnstores indexes to reduce the file footprint. If you have to store large files, you should consider designing you application so that it stores this data in blob store rather than in the DB itself.